# How to evaluate Yolov5 on a different eval set than it was trained on?

Tags: yolov5

When I finished training the YOLO V5 model, evaluation metrics such as precision, recall, and AP (average precision) of the model on the validation data were shown. Is it possible to view those evaluation metrics from a trained model against a new images? (note: the new image has its annotation file)

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate on you existing data:

```bash
python val.py --weights yolov5s.pt --data your_dataset.yaml --img 640
```

To evaluate on new data:

```bash
python val.py --weights yolov5s.pt --data your_new_dataset.yaml --img 640
```